# JSP increment table row calculate sum and back to jsp with Beans

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I got a table in JSP. there I have 3 input text with values, and when I click submit then I got again the JSP table with one row more with the result of the three input.

index.jsp this jsp is where I got the table with the values and sum then I submit to servlet

```
<form method="post" action="Servlet">
        <table id="sum_table">
          <tbody>
          <tr>
                        <td class="numtotal">TOTAL</td>
                        <td class="num">1</td><td class="num">2</td><td class="num">3</td><td class="num">
                    </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" value="${bean.sum}"maxlength=3 readonly="readonly"></TD>
                <c:forEach items="${bean.values}" var="value" varStatus="loop">
                    <c:if test="${not loop.first and loop.index % 3 == 0}">
                        </tr><tr>
                    </c:if>
                    <td><input type="text" name="value" value="${value}"  maxlength="2"/></td>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
             <p><input type="submit" id="submit"/></p>
             <p><input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="+"/></p>
    </form>
```

Servlet.java Here I set the values and the sum of values and send to the index jsp

```
Bean bean = new Bean(); 
        String[] values= request.getParameterValues("value");

        if (values == null) {
            values= new String[3];
            for(int i=0; i< 3;i++) {
                values[i]= "0";
            }
        }
        Integer sum= 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        {
            bean.setSum(sum = sum + Integer.valueOf(values[i]));
            bean.setValues(values);
        }   
         request.setAttribute("bean", bean);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

This is my bean Class:

```
public class Bean {

    String[] values;
    Integer sum;

    public Integer getSum() {return sum;}
    public void setSum(Integer integer) {this.sum = integer;}

    public String[] getValues() {return values;}
    public void setValues(String[] valores) {this.values= values;}

}
```

With one row works ok example:

```
TOTAL | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE3
 10   |    2   |   3    |  5
```

But If I do a button that increment this row for do another sum, of three more values is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to display multiple rows of three values, you should display the total on its own row. Next, it's not really easy to deal with multiple submit buttons in a form, because you will have to test what is the label of the button that was clicked and it leads to complex operations as soon as you go into i18n. You should considere using a checkbox and a single submit button.

Also, you have `bean.setValues(values)` in your loop when it should be after the loop.

Anyway an `<input type="button" .../>` does not submit anything and can only trigger javascript.

Now I suppose you found a way to determine in your servlet that you want to add a new row (checkbox or 2 submit buttons). You could change your `bean.setValues(values)` (gone out of loop ...) to something like :

```
if (needAddRow) {
    String[] val2 = new String[values.length + 3];
    val2[0] = 0;
    val2[1] = 0;
    val2[2] = 0;
    for (int i=0; i< values.length; i++) {
        val[i+3] = values[i];
    }
    bean.setValues(val2);
}
else {
    bean.setValues(values);
}
```

Beware : untested ...